# Trying to move text between two forms -- "is inaccessible due to protection level"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've seen questions like this posted before, but I'm having trouble understanding how to fix it. I'm hoping someone here will take a look at what I have, and be able to explain what needs changed in a way I can grasp.

So, I have two forms. The 'main' form (called Viewer) displays information that is loaded from a database. The second form (called Loader) is made to select what group of data to be loaded.

I thought the easiest way would be to use the Loader to select the data group via a dropdown box (called LoaderCombo), then pull the text over to the Viewer and use that to grab the database info.

I'm attempting to use the following:

```
public void LoaderScript()
{
    NameRef.Text = Convert.ToString(Loader.LoaderCombo.Text);
}
```

NameRef is just a text box that would store the name of the data group to load. It could just as easily be a variable for my purposes. The issue here is that "LoaderCombo" is is throwing an error that it "is inaccessible due to its protection level".

Is there a simpler way for me to pull the text off of a combo box on the Loader form? That's literally ALL I'm trying to do between forms, so it shouldn't be that difficult, should it?

Comment: It means LoaderCombo is not a public property of Loader. It's likely either private or protected. If you share the declaration of LoaderCombo we can help more.

Comment: Well presumably `LoaderCombo` is private. So you *could* make it internal instead - or expose a property which returns `LoaderCombo.Text` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `LoaderCombo` is `public`, or better yet, create a read only property on your Loader form called `CurrentSelection` like so:

```
public string CurrentSelection 
{
  get { return LoaderCombo.Text; }
}
```

And then in viewer, access `Loader.CurrentSelection` rather than `Loader.LoaderCombo.Text`.

With the property approach, if you change the control setup on your `Loader` form, you won't be breaking code in your `Viewer` form- you really should try to design software so that things that interact with other things need to know as  little as possible about each other.

Comment: I'm a freakin' idiot, this was exactly the problem. It was set as a private item instead of public. As soon as I changed it to public, the error disappeared. And thanks, I will change it to CurrentSelection. I had done that a few other places, but I'm picking up the project after a six-month hiatus, so I've gotten a little rusty with my coding. :p

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck getting unrusted!